# Referencing files inside build (Docker)

Tags: docker, elasticsearch-marvel

I use boot2docker and want to build a simple docker image with the Dockerfile:

```
# Pull base image.
FROM elasticsearch

# Install Marvel plugin

RUN \
    && export ES_HOME=/usr/share/elasticsearch  \
    && cd $ES_HOME  \
    && bin/plugin  -u  file:///c/Users/buliov1/dev/elastic/plugins/marvel-latest.zip -i elasticsearch/marvel/latest
```

The path **/c/Users/buliov1/dev/elastic/plugins/marvel-latest.zip** is present and accessible on the machine where I build the dockerfile .
The problem is that inside the build i get 
`Failed: FileNotFoundException[/c/Users/buliov1/dev/elastic/plugins/marvel-latest.zip (No such file or directory)]`.

I searched through the documentation and the only solution I see is to use ADD/COPY and copy first the file inside the image and then run the command that uses the file.
I don't know how exactly docker build works but , **is there a way to build it without copying the file first?**

Comment: It seems to me that the Windows syntax is not allowed in a Dockerfile, as Docker runs on Linux. On Windows, boot2docker runs a Linux minimal VM inside Virtualbox. From that Linux VM inside Virtualbox, I doubt you can do a `dir file:///c/Users/buliov1/dev/elastic/plugins/marvel-latest.zip`or such. On a sidenote, I would use `ENV ES_HOME=/usr/share/elasticsearch` rather than your export

Comment: the same problem with ENV ES_HOME is that it cannot be expanded at build time.   BTW  /c/Users/buliov1/ path is a  share inside boot2docker-vm shared with the windows host by default created when boot2docker is initialized it is very useful  for mounting it forward to containers for quick prototyping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `docker build` process is running *inside* Docker containers and has no access to the host filesystem.  The only way to get files into the build environment is through the use of the `ADD` or `COPY` mechanism (or by fetching them over the network using, e.g., `curl` or `wget` or something).

Comment: After all I used a COPY to /tmp/ and run it from there. Normally I wouldn't need copy since bin/plugin  can install from a a preconfigured remote repository (like apt-get) but I couldn't configure the proxy inside build process for && bin/plugin command for this image.